# Docker auto spawning required connected container types on demand

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, microservices, weave

Is there a way to systematically clone/scale Docker containers as microservices so that a bottleneck caused by too few instances of a particular container type(web, routing, database, etc.) is eliminated?

That the system essentially reconfigure itself by responding to different load profiles.  Also that containers in the system are discoverable and in communications as services.

If this was on an EC2 instance, that it also know when system resources were maxed and use Weave to connect the new containers in a newly AWS scaled instance to balance load?  on NodeJS.

Comment: Can you use ELBs and auto scaling groups with appropriate policies?

Comment: I'm *trying* to build such a thing in [autodock](https://github.com/prologic/autodock) and the new plugin autodock-autoscale (*not published yet*).

Comment: Also an an aside; I've found in my experience AWS's ELB(s) and Auto Scaling facilities quite slow and don't really scale instantaneously like many Docker-based solutions like hipache.

Comment: You could probably bake your own ASG using CloudWatch alarms and their API

Comment: We have an new guide that might of interest: http://weave.works/guides/service-discovery-with-weave-aws-ecs.html